# What is the purpose of a deeply cut stud in interior walls?

Tags: studs

As I have worked on my 30-year-old house, I found some interior 2x6 wall studs are deeply cut, clearly done at the time the home was built.  The cuts are somewhere between 1/3 and 1/2 along the length of the stud.

[image: notched 2x6 interior stud]!

I'm guessing that maybe this was done on green studs to prevent the walls from warping as the studs dried, but it's unclear to me if this is #1 common, and #2 whether I should be adding sister studs as I come across these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s an old “sheetrockers” trick. When an interior non-load bearing wall stud is warped, it can be brought “back in line” by cutting it and relieving the stress.

I’ve only seen this done on interior non-load bearing walls AND when there’s just one or two in any one wall. If you have several in a row or they’re in a bearing wall, you should consider reinforcing a few studs.

If it hasn’t been a problem, I’d be cautious about fixing something that’s not broken. Banging the studs with a hammer could cause other problems.

Comment: I agree on all points. I've made a few such fixes myself on remodels or when dramatic warping occurs due to moisture during construction. Typically we'd lay in a new stud alongside, but one here or there isn't a problem.

Comment: yeah, if you still want to sister this stud, and do it without banging: use screws.